# Access Windows files stored on the computer via the WSL?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On a Windows running computer, can we access files stored on the computer via the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) ?

For example I'm using the Ubuntu WSL version on my Windows 10 computer. Using Ubuntu WSL, can I run a `cat` command on a text file stored in *My Documents* on the C: disk ?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running.  If this is possible entirely depends on the version your running

Comment: If it helps, I know it's possible using RDP.  Griffon's IT Library created an [automated script](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12551) I've been using for 2yrs to auto-configure RDP on Ubuntu Hyper-V VMs with `xrdp`.

Comment: Here is a WSL FAQ blog post: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#how-do-i-access-my-c-drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern versions of Ubuntu WSL, Windows system drives are mounted under `/mnt/` on the Linux filesystem. *e.g. `C:\Users\test\test.txt` --> `/mnt/c/Users/test/test.txt`*

If you wanted to `cat` out a file stored under `C:\[USER-NAME]\Documents\[FILE-NAME]`, you could run `cat /mnt/[USER-NAME]/Documents/[FILE-NAME]` in WSL.

Comment: You might want to define what "modern versions" of WSL are exactly.

Comment: @Ramhound Valid, but I'm not sure how to do research into that. Would you suggest me use alternate vocabulary instead?

Comment: @ifconfig A specific version number would be helpful